# MariaDB JDBC Client Logging

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, mariadb

Is there any way to log queries *in java* using the MariaDB jdbc driver?

With the MySQL driver, I am using

```
profileSQL=true
logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger
```

to log queries on dev machines (makes debugging a lot easier).

I realize things like [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) exist - do I need to use a library like that or does the mariadb driver have something built in?

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.5.0, [log is supported](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/#log-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

As Per Lundberg already stated, logging is possible since version 1.5.0, see [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/#log-parameters).

To activate it, I added `&log=true` to my database URL. However, this was not sufficient. As explained [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#using-logging-options), the following steps are also needed:

First, we need to add some dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>[1.4.0,1.7.25]</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then we need to configure logback like in the given example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.mariadb.jdbc" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The "trace" log level gives a lot of information, so you might want to use another one. The currently supported log levels are: trace, debug, info, warn or error

Answer (score -1):

Currently there is no way to log sql queries from  mariadb java client.

You can see this link:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/client-libraries/mariadb-java-client/about-the-mariadb-java-client/

However an alternative is you can use **dumpQueriesOnException** if that can help.

Comment: In the meantime, the link actually proves the opposite - it is possible. Would have been better to also copy the text stating that logging is not possible.