# MariaDB JDBC Client Logging not working for me

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

Since 1.5.0, the MariaDB Connector/J JDBC driver [supports a `log` option](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/#log), but if I switch that on (using 1.5.5), I don't see any log messages.

This is the URL I'm using:

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/yona?log=true
```

Am I doing it wrongly or do I need to do something extra? I searched the internet, also for the other log options like `slowQueryThresholdNanos`, but it looks like nobody uses this.

Regards,
Bert

P.S. This question is actually a duplicate of [this older one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609478/mariadb-jdbc-client-logging), but at that time the log option didn't exist yet.

Comment: Do you have slf4j installed, and correctly configured logging?

Comment: Yes, I get plenty log messages from Spring and other components, including my own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the logging level, e.g. in logback.xml:

`<logger name="org.mariadb.jdbc" level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The logging is effective, given a message like this:

    o.m.j.i.p.AbstractConnectProtocol        : server data max_allowed_packet : 4194304

But I don't get any statements logged

Comment: It does work for you, surely, but the info it produces is ineffective. Or do you really mean the opposite? I was also disappointed to discover that the only SQL it logs is at TRACE level, and buried in multi-line binary output. I think you should try p6spy, I got a lot further with it.

Comment: https://proxysql.com/ can also be a useful tool for getting more insights into what database queries are being executed (among other usages). Free under the GPL.